# In node.js, how do I get the Content-Length header in response to http.get()?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following script and it seems as though node is not including the Content-Length header in the response object. I need to know the length before consuming the data and since the data could be quite large, I'd rather not buffer it.

```
http.get('http://www.google.com', function(res){    

    console.log(res.headers['content-length']); // DOESN'T EXIST
});
```

I've navigated all over the object tree and don't see anything. All other headers are in the 'headers' field.

Any ideas?

Comment: Drop a for(var k in res.headers) { console.log(k, res.headers[k]); } to see all the keys available in the headers. Could be a capitalization thing.

Comment: Thanks, but I already inspected the object tree and see everything EXCEPT the content-length header.

Comment: @CharlieKey [All the header fields' names in the response object are lowercase, no matter what case they actually have.](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_message_headers)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

www.google.com does not send a `Content-Length`.  It uses [chunked encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding), which you can tell by the `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` header.

If you want the size of the response body, listen to `res`'s `data` events, and add the size of the received buffer to a counter variable.  When `end` fires, you have the final size.

If you're worried about large responses, abort the request once your counter goes above how ever many bytes.

Comment: Ouch. I was using fiddler to inspect the response and didn't realize fiddler was adding that header in.

Comment: @mike: Yes, if Fiddler is not in Streaming mode, it will buffer the entire response internally and then send a `Content-Length` header to the browser.  Click the **Stream** button in the toolbar and Fiddler will not do this.

Answer (score 5):

Not every server will send `content-length` headers.

For example:

```
http.get('http://www.google.com', function(res) {
    console.log(res.headers['content-length']); // undefined
});
```

But if you request SO:

```
http.get('http://stackoverflow.com/', function(res) {
    console.log(res.headers['content-length']); // 1192916
});
```

You are correctly pulling that header from the response, google just doesn't send it on their homepage (they use chunked encoding instead).